# How do I get a thread's PID?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

In the following code, I'm initiating a process with some worker function.

```
def listener(ttl, port):
    print "Started listenning on port: " + str(port) + " for: " + str(ttl) + " seconds."
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('localhost', port))
    serversocket.listen(1)
    time.sleep(ttl)
    print "Finished listening on port: " + str(port)

def main():
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target = listener, args = (20,5555))
    thread1.start()
    print thread1.get_ident()
    thread1.join()
    print "main completed"
```

How can I get a PID of `thread1`?

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 if that makes a difference.

Comment: PID (process ID) or TID (thread ID)?

Comment: PID - process id
Threads on UNIX are implemented as processes

Comment: In Linux kernel, yes, but in user land? There is a difference between a thread and a process, e.g. a thread shares memory with other threads where a process doesn't

Comment: In Linux is seems that PID = process ID and SPID (system PID) = thread ID. See `ps -T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pid is a process identifier. Threads are not processes. ([Cite](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/715571))

That said,

```
os.getpid()
```

should do it.

Comment: I should get the PID from the main function, not sure how "os.getpid() should do it...
BTW, I'm almost sure that threads in UNIX are processes.

Comment: Your thread1 will have the same PID as your main().  thread1.get_ident() will get an identifier, but it's not the same as a PID.

Comment: I have created several threads, and each one of them got different PID. I believe you confuse Windows to Unix.

Comment: On Linux, threads are numbered using LWP numbers. LWP and PID numbers come from the same pool.

Comment: threads in unix can be found in `/proc/<PID>/task/<TID>/` and their structure resembles the original process they come from (I'm currently unsure of how to get the `<TID>` value in python)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a thread's PID with

```py
thread.native_id
```

or the current one's PID with

```py
threading.get_native_id()
```

**NOTE:** The `native_id` property and the `get_native_id` method are only supported in Python 3.8+